# Vlookup referencing from a different file

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Trying to vlookup from a different file, One of the files is in a different folder, im getting o as the lookup output, .I need to lookup close to a 100,000 rows, how do i go about that, The lookup result is a string, but when i declared myvlookupresult as string, the code ran but there was no output.
Can someone Pls help

```
Private Sub VLookup2()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim myLookupValue As String
    Dim myFirstColumn As Long
    Dim myLastColumn As Long
    Dim myColumnIndex As Long
    Dim myFirstRow As Long
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim myVLookupResult As Long
    Dim myTableArray As Range
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("COCO PILOT MTS_2612").Sheets("Sheet1")

    myLookupValue = wb1.Range("B").Value
    myFirstColumn = 1
    myLastColumn = 3
    myColumnIndex = 3
    myFirstRow = 2
    myLastRow = 500

    With Workbooks("master zonal head lsit.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set myTableArray = .Range(.Cells(myFirstRow, myFirstColumn), .Cells(myLastRow, myLastColumn))
    End With

     myVLookupResult = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(myLookupValue, myTableArray, myColumnIndex, False)
    Range("C").Value = myVLookupResult

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the following lines are incorrect...

```
myLookupValue = wb1.Range("B").Value
```

and

```
Range("C").Value = myVLookupResult
```

You've omitted the row reference.  So it should be something like this...

```
myLookupValue = wb1.Range("B2").Value
```

and

```
Range("C2").Value = myVLookupResult
```

Secondly, you have `On Error Resume Next` at the beginning of your code.  This will hide any and all errors.  If you're going to use it, it needs to be handled correctly.  However, in this case, there's no need to use it in order to deal with errors returned by VLookup().

Instead of using `WorksheetFunction.VLookup()`, we can use `Application.VLookup()`.  This way, a ***non-breaking*** error occurs when there's no match, for which we can test using `IsError()`.  Here's an example...

```
Dim myVLookupResult As Variant

myVLookupResult = Application.VLookup(myLookupValue, myTableArray, myColumnIndex, False)

If Not IsError(myVLookupResult) Then
    Range("C2").Value = myVLookupResult
Else
    Range("C2").Value = "N/A"
End If
```

Note that myVLookupResult is declared as a Variant, since VLookup() can return an error in addition to a string.

***EDIT***

To enter the formula in a range of cells, and then convert the formulas to values, try the following...

```
With Range("C2:C" & myLastRow)
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2," & myTableArray.Address(external:=True) & "," & myColumnIndex & ",0)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just another thing, is there any way to do this for all rows?(using the row.count function to get to the last row or something like that, have no idea on how i can add that in the code)

Comment: For all rows, you can simply use `Range("C2:C" & myLastRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2," & myTableArray.Address(external:=True) & "," & myColumnIndex & ",0)"`.

Comment: Also, if you want to convert those formulas into values, see my edited post.